# How does apt keep track of BUILD (source) dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, packaging, aptitude

I want to download all (recursive) build dependencies to be able to build apt (debian) package from source. However, when I `apt-get install path/*.debs` with debs that I got by `apt build-dep --download-only --assume-yes <package>` apt finds additional packages to be installed and fails, even with `--no-install-recommends --ignore-missing`.  [My specific issue got no answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491862/how-to-list-download-the-recursive-build-dependencies-of-a-debian-package). Then I've investigated further and I have not seen those additional packages in output of successfully run `apt build-dep <package>`, therefore I've realized (obviously) **build dependencies should be tracked differently.** How?

I mean there are `Depends/Suggests/Recommends` fields in a deb file, but I have not seen additional fields related to sourcing. `build-dep` resulted in ~150 deb files found, but during installation of them as packages, `apt` found additional dependencies.

I've tried to read
[Packaging/SourcePackage - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/SourcePackage)

> Source packages provide you with all of the necessary files to compile
> or otherwise, build the desired piece of software. It consists, in its
> simplest form, of three files:
> The upstream tarball with .tar.gz ending
> A description file with .dsc ending.

```
apt source cinnamon-settings-daemon
```

Got `cinnamon-settings-daemon_5.0.4+uma.tar.xz.`, search have not found `.dsc` file inside, maybe Linux Mint (OS I use) implemented modified Debian implementation?

[BuildingTutorial - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial)

> apt provides a way of easily installing all the needed dependencies:
> Example 1: node-pretty-ms
> sudo apt build-dep node-pretty-ms
> However I have not found description how system keep track of those.

Inside one of downloaded deb files I got with `apt build-dep` I do not see additional section with dependencies for building/source:

```
$ apt show /media/ramdrive/debs/cinnamon-settings-daemon/autoconf_2.69-11.1_all.deb
Package: autoconf
Version: 2.69-11.1
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Ben Pfaff <pfaffben@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1905 kB
Depends: perl (>> 5.005), m4 (>= 1.4.13), debianutils (>= 1.8)
Recommends: automake | automaken
Suggests: autoconf-archive, gnu-standards, autoconf-doc, libtool, gettext
Breaks: gettext (<< 0.10.39), pkg-config (<< 0.25-1.1)
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/
Task: ubuntustudio-video
Download-Size: 321 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
Description: automatic configure script builder
 The standard for FSF source packages.  This is only useful if you
 write your own programs or if you extensively modify other people's
 programs.
 .
 For an extensive library of additional Autoconf macros, install the
 `autoconf-archive' package.
 .
 This version of autoconf is not compatible with scripts meant for
 Autoconf 2.13 or earlier.
```

Added 1:

One of two packages still listed as "additional" during `apt-get install --no-install-recommends` is `libpulse0:i386`. Doing

```
~$ apt-cache rdepends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances libpulse0:i386 # got ~ 1000 lines

find /path_to_debs/cinnamon-settings-daemon -name *.deb | xargs apt-cache show | grep Package | awk '{print $2}' # ~ 160 debs
```

and using `vlookup` in LibreOffice Calc found out it reverse depends on to be installed `pulseaudio` and `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` via e.g. on about ~300th line of rdepends:

```
libcanberra-pulse:i386
ReverseDepends:
pulseaudio
```

Added 2022/01/06:

I understood the cause of initial issue, if interested, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70601238/14557599 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684975/446998. I was not able to reproduce my claim in this question (I have not seen those additional packages in output of successfully run `apt build-dep <package>`), maybe I run the command on another system blinded by my incorrect assumption from realizing differences between them mattered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build dependencies are set by the package maintainer with a `Build-Depends:` (and sometimes `Build-Depends-Indep:`) settings in the [debian/control](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#control) file of the source package.

`Depends`, `Recommends`, and `Suggestions` are needed when a package is installed (or about to be installed), so that data is in the Packages file.   `Build-Depends*` are only needed when the package is being built, so is not.

BTW, as you can see from either downloading the source package or using the package tracker (e.g. https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/a/autoconf/control-2.71-2) the `Build-Depends*` settings for `autoconf` are:

```
Build-Depends-Indep: texinfo (>= 4.6), m4 (>= 1.4.13),
 texlive-base, texlive-plain-generic, texlive-latex-base,
 texlive-latex-recommended, texlive-fonts-recommended, help2man, cm-super
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 13)
```

Also BTW, this is a simplification.  It's enough for most packages, but some packages also have `Build-Conflicts*:` settings for packages that can not be installed for the build to be successful.

If you haven't already, I suggest that you read the [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) - some of this is specific to Debian package maintainers, but most of it is generic "how do I build a .deb package" info.

Comment: Thank you. For `cinnamon-settings-daemon` control file `Build-Depends:` lists ~ 30 lines. `apt build-dep` downloaded ~ 160. Where have it got the rest? There are not build-depends of those in initial control AFAIK as those in control file are already binary, there is not need to recursively build those.-----If the answer is: obviously these are binary depends of those in control, then why has `apt build-dep` missed several dependencies (as I cannot install downloaded set of debs with `apt-get install`)?

Comment: Why those missed binary dependencies are not needed when I install with `apt build-dep`?

Comment: if a package Build-Depends on `foo-dev` and the binary foo-dev package depends on `bar`, there's no need for the Build-Depends to contain `bar`.

Comment: and no need to install `bar` to build the package?

Comment: bar will be automatically installed when foo-dev is installed.

Comment: BTW, if the package you're building requires, say `baz` and foo-dev only Suggests or Recommends baz, then you'd have to explicitly list baz in the Build-Depends line.   Suggested packages are not auto-installed, and it's possible to configure apt to not install Recommended packages by default (e.g. with `APT { Install-Recommends "False";};` in an apt.conf file)

Comment: In general it is clear. But please see my question again and the first comment - why some dependencies of `foo-dev`are not downloaded / installed when I run `build-dep` but needed for `install`?

Comment: I've (as mentioned) tried to `install --no-install-recommends --ignore-missing`, still it cannot fix missing (couple of debs in that particular case). in that particular case these are i386 and at least one is upgrade - maybe it matters...

Comment: I have not noticed any other i386 files in outputs of installed debs.

Comment: apt resolves dependencies, that's it's primary job.  One or more of the packages being installed must depend on the i386 packages.  If a package is already installed then apt won't upgrade it unless there is a versioned dependency that requires a newer version to be installed.    Tracing dependency chains can be very difficult, and there can be multiple viable solutions to resolving them.  That's why we have tools (like apt) that are good at it.

Comment: And my question is driven by wish to understand these tools better. Why `build-dep` command does not need some dependencies whereas `install` goes. I might file a possible bug if there is no explanation. I don't know where to file that one.

Comment: I understood the cause of initial issue, if interested, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70601238/14557599 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684975/446998. I was not able to reproduce my claim in this question, may I run the command on another system blinded by my incorrect assumption from realizing differences between them mattered, thanks for help!